# Reading In Multiple Data types from a .txt file where one of the strings has spaces C++

Tags: c++, types, text-files, getline

I have a text file that looks like this:

Car, CN, 819481, maintenance, false, NONE

Car, SLSF, 46871, business,true, Memphis

Car, AOK, 156, tender, true, San Francisco

(the commas are tabs in actuality, but I was unable to get them to format properly on this site)

I have an object called Car which i am reading the code into and outputting using the output at the bottom of the code. My current code can read in all of the first 5 data types, but I am having trouble with reading in the last column where there can be spaces. I have tried using getline, but to no avail.

Here is the code that I have for the function that takes the txt as inputs

```
void input()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("input.txt",fstream::in);

    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"input failed"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    string type;
    string reportingMark;
    int carNumber;
    string kind;
    bool loaded;
    string destination;

    while(inputFile.peek() != EOF)
    {
        inputFile>>type>>reportingMark>>carNumber>>kind>>loaded;
        while(inputFile.peek() == ' ')
            inputFile.get();
            getline(inputFile, destination);

        Car temp(reportingMark, carNumber, kind, loaded, destination);
        temp.output();
    }

    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading a whole line at a time as string and then parsing and extracting the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `>>` operator, use `getline`:

```
string line;
while (getline(inputFile, line) {
  // split line by tabs or commas
}
```

Example split function:

```
vector<string> explode(string &str, char separator) {
  vector<string> result;
  string tmp;

  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
    if (str[i] == separator) {
      result.push_back(tmp);
      tmp.clear();
    } else tmp += str[i];
  }

  if (tmp.size() > 0)
    result.push_back(tmp);

  return result;
}
```

I hope that `std::vector` isn't hard for you. Example loading code (instead `while(inputFile.peek() != EOF) { ... }`):

```
string line;
while (getline(inputFile, line) {
  vector<string> data = split(line, '\t');  // Or use ASCII code 9
  if (data.size() != 5) {
    cout << "Invalid line!" << endl;
    continue;
  }

  Car temp(data[0], data[1], stoi(data[2]), data[3], data[4]);
  temp.output();
}
```

Don't copy-paste this code, I see that you have bool variables etc. that is not handled.

Answer (score 0):

The STL function `std::getline` accepts a delimiter as a third argument which means you can pass a `\t` to read tab separated values. For the last value, just read it without specifying the delimiter which will mean the overloaded version of the function will be called where the delimiter is `\n`.

Read one line at a time, separate into tokens, convert to required datatype.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3fa753193fda8f0) is a working example. It can be improved though. Also you should handle exceptions thrown by `std::stoi` during `std::string` to `int` conversion.