# How to read a number from a file and use it as a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

Let's say I have a file I'm reading  that goes something like this :

```
#character         posX      posY //commentary line: explains what it represents
CharacterName1     50.0       0.0

CharacterName2     32.0       50.0
```

The goal here is to be able to read the posX et posY and convert them in my C++ program into 2 double variables x and y.

For now, all I'm able to do is to start reading the file and see if the line corresponds to an empty line or a commentary line.
Then, if the reading line finds the corresponding character name, i should be able to to continue reading this line to get the posX and the posY, but I have no clue on how to do that. I don't know how to skip the blank and how to start reading the number and how to finish reading it to then convert it into double.

Any idea on how I should do that ?

I truly hope this is clear enough.

Thank you in advance.

Attempt example

```cpp
void loadMap(std::string const& filepath) {


    std::ifstream infile(filepath.c_str());
    
    if(infile.fail()) {  
        
        std::cerr << "Error... " << std::endl;
        
    } else { /opening occured correctly
       
        while ( !infile.eof() ) {
            
            std::string line; 
            std::getline(infile, line);
            
            if ( (line[0] != '#') or (line.empty()) ) { //if line not comment or not empty
                  
                
                if( line.find("CharacterName1") ) {.......
```

Then I'm lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Numeric Data from a Text File in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c)

Comment: I saw this question before posting but I don't really understand the answers proposed.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: @PalLaden, I edited my question with an example, I hope it clears things out

Comment: Please read this carefully: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1968)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I will do the changes at the end. Thank you very much for the share. Sadly, it does not really solve my problem here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading In Multiple Data types from a .txt file where one of the strings has spaces C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663178/reading-in-multiple-data-types-from-a-txt-file-where-one-of-the-strings-has-spa)

Comment: @dixit_chandra Still not, sorry. I understand the code but I don't see how I can implement it in the same way for my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this piece of code will help.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace  std;         //change headers and namespaces; included for ease of use;

vector<string> split(const string &text, const char sep) {
    vector<string> tokens;
    std::size_t start = 0, end = 0;
    while ((end = text.find(sep, start)) not_eq string::npos) {
        tokens.emplace_back(text.substr(start, end - start));
        start = end + 1;
    }
    tokens.emplace_back(text.substr(start));
    return tokens;
}

    int main()
    {
       ofstream outdata;
       outdata.open("example.txt");
       if( not outdata ) {
          cerr << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
          exit(1);
       }
       outdata<<"CharacterName1"<<','<<10.0<<','<<40.0<<endl; //writing data into file
       outdata<<"CharacterName2"<<','<<20.0<<','<<30.0<<endl;
       outdata<<"CharacterName3"<<','<<30.0<<','<<20.0<<endl;
       outdata<<"CharacterName4"<<','<<40.0<<','<<10.0<<endl;
       outdata.close();

        ifstream inputFile;
        inputFile.open("example.txt",fstream::in);
        if (inputFile.fail())
        {
            cerr<<"Error: file could not be opened"<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        string line;
        vector<string> col1;
        vector<double> col2;
        vector<double> col3;
        while (getline(inputFile, line))
        {
            if(not line.empty()){

            auto lineData = split(line, ','); //separator can change in your case
            col1.emplace_back(lineData[0]);
            col2.emplace_back(std::stof(lineData[1]));
            col3.emplace_back(std::stof(lineData[2]));
            }
        }
        for(int i =0; i<(int) col1.size();i++)         //printing the data;
            cout<<col1[i]<<"\t"<<col2[i]<<"\t"<<col3[i]<<"\n";
       return 0;
    }
```

understand the above logic through the following approach:

1. read each line of the file.
2. for each line we will separate the column data through the `split(string, sep)` function which will return a `vector<string>` containing data of the row. Here `sep` is the separator used in the file; as I made input file comma-separated, I used `','`
3. converting the returned `vector<string>` type row-data into appropriate data type and storing in respective column vector `col1, col2, col3`.
4. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408245/3892473) of split() functionality.

> for another column that may have some missing data
> you can add some logic like

```
if(lineData.size() > 3)
    col4.emplace_back(std::stof(lineData[3]));
else
    col4.emplace_back(0.0);
```

after `col3.emplace_back(std::stof(lineData[2]));` line.

Comment: It probably took you a while to write this out. Why not complete the answer with adequate explanation? I would also remove the first two lines too - you don't often see them in production code.

Comment: I've never seen anybody unironically use `not_eq`. Do you *really* think that's more readable than `!=`?

Comment: @Bathsheba I am awaiting a confirmation from the post owner whether it is the required solution or not so that I can help with a better explanation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's certainly idiosyncratic but perhaps becoming less so if you come from Python. It certainly puts my head into a "this is not C++" mode. Yes, I find it harder to read fluently.

Comment: @dixit_chandra: Stack Overflow has a philosophy consistent with your not necessarily targeting the answer at the OP. It's here to help the wider community. Perhaps therefore the community is asking for a better explanation?

Comment: @Bathsheba Python uses `!=`, not `not_eq`. I’m fine with `and`, `or` and `not` (I use them myself), I’m talking specifically about `not_eq`.

Comment: not_eq is what preferred in my organization so its due to habit

Comment: @dixit_chandra 

Comment: @dixit_chandra: We gotta get you another job!

Comment: @Bathsheba sure help me out 

Comment: @Bathsheba I recently started contributing to stack-overflow; so I'm not much aware of community guidelines; after your comment, I updated the answer with an explanation of my approach.  Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @dixit_chandra: Thank you. Downvote converted to upvote!

Comment: @dixit_chandra Thank you a lot. I'm getting somewhere now. I just have to find a way to implement another data because it is not only posX and posY for everything. Sometimes I have 3 variables. If I follow the same procedure but add col4 for the 3rd variables, would it be initialized at 0 if none is to be find ?

Comment: @Munshine added some logic in the answer which can help you with this problem; however, this logic won't help if you have missing data in columns 1,2 or 3.

Comment: @dixit_chandra I really appreciate your help and time to answer my question. I should be able to do what I want now with the informations you provided me. If I don't, well, shame on me .. Thank you a lot and have a nice day :)

Comment: @Munshine never hesitate in asking even the silliest thing, but before that try by yourself. reach out to the community for further help if needed.

Comment: @dixit_chandra I'm now able to initialize my variables by the code inspired by yours. I can not say how much I appreciate your help. Big thank you, it saved me.  Only thing left is to find out why my code is crashing when it come across a blank line or at the end of the file. I will figure it out !